# Double dual of coherent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a noetherian integral scheme. $E$ is a vector bundle, and $F$ is a subsheaf, so $F\subset E$. Is it true that $F^{\vee\vee}\subset E^{\vee\vee}$?

I am not able to prove this.

If $Q$ cokernel, then,
$0\rightarrow F\rightarrow E\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 0$.

If we do dualizing for above sequence, we get $\mathcal{E}xt$ sheaves right? Hence we get

$0\rightarrow Q^{\vee}\rightarrow E^{\vee}\rightarrow F^{\vee}\rightarrow \mathcal{E}xt^1(Q,O_X)\rightarrow....$.

Dualizing again, how we get $F^{\vee\vee}\subset E^{\vee\vee}$?

Comment: We always have a natural map of the double duals. Since everything is torsion free,  to check injectivity, suffices to do this at the generic point, where it is obvious.